# Edit MEANJS list in the list page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN JS, i am trying to edit the list items on the list page, but it shows the error as below. i have initiated the data using `ng-init="find()"` for the list and `ng-init="findOne()"` for individual data.

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
```

**HTML**
Below i the form inside the controller where it initiates the find() and findOne().

```
<div ng-controller="OrdersController" ng-init="find()">
                <div> 
                    <div class="order-filter">
                        <div ng-repeat="order in orders">
                            <form ng-init="findOne()" name="orderForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="update(orderForm.$valid)" novalidate>
                                <input type="text" class="" ng-model="order.title">
                                <input type="text" class="" ng-model="order.content">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.update = function (isValid) {
    $scope.error = null;

    if (!isValid) {
        $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'orderForm');

        return false;
    }

    var order = $scope.order;

    order.$update(function () {
        $location.path('orders/' + order._id);
    }, function (errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
    });
};
$scope.find = function () {
    Orders.query(function loadedOrders(orders) {
        orders.forEach(appendFood);
        $scope.orders = orders;
    });
};
$scope.findOne = function () {
        $scope.order = Orders.get({
            orderId: $stateParams.orderId
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your Orders Service which probably is using $resource to provide your API requests (Orders.query)

It should look something like this:

```
function OrdersService($resource) {
    return $resource('api/orders/:orderId', {
      orderId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
```

The style may be different depending on which version of mean you're using. By default, the $resource query will expect an array of results, but if for some reason you've set "isArray" to false then it will expect an object.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource